# google places API finding place

Tags: android, google-places-api, reverse-geocoding, google-places

To use google places API in our Android application, a key is needed. I have got a key now. But I don't know about how do i use it in my application and how to do search for a specific place. Also, please can anyone explain about what are the prerequisites for using Places API in my application. I have searched manything. But I didn't understood that.

```
         1) Can anyone explain please with complete code.

         2) Also, explain how do I search for a place by using latitude and longitude values in Place API
```

Answer (score 0):

Please refer my answer on [Google Places Api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14252476/ho-do-i-use-google-places-to-find-a-place-in-android/14252610#14252610)

Pass Your location to search and your api key in url and my code also shows how to find nearest place.

Thanks

Comment: will you post the complete code please, because i'm getting some errors also I don't know where do i type that code (under any method or OnCreate) Please explain. I'm new to android

Comment: You can put my code in any method such getPlaces("like hospitals"); and call this from your onCreate method of activity

Comment: It shows error when converting string to JSon at line String res=JSonResponse(url)

Comment: Json Response is another function in which you have to write your HttpClient for getting response refer this http://www.androidsnippets.com/executing-a-http-post-request-with-httpclient